# How to mark a folder using Linux so that it appears as hidden in Windows

Tags: hidden

There seems to be very little information out there on how to do this or even if it's possible..

Does anyone know?

Ps. I'm using GPFS and running mkdir on a folder then viewing it using Windows share. I know I can mark the folder as hidden Windows, but I want to know how to do it via Linux (if it's possible).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer!

Modify the /etc/samba/smb.conf file like so (for the relevant share):

```
hide files = /<folder_that_you_want_hidden>/
```

Then restart the Samba service:

```
/etc/init.d/smb restart
```

Your folder will now be hidden in Windows.